# How to find the implement python file of the python built in modules, ie itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using anaconda in Windows os, I am trying to realize the structure of the whole python environment.

For example, I want to check the implementation file of the module `itertools`. However, when I take a look into the folder which path is `anaconda3/envs/my_envs/Lib` there's no any python file named `itertools.py`.

How can I find the exactly file that contained all these [implementations code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) from docs.python.org

Comment: How to find: open the interpreter, import the desired module, type the imported module's name, press Return. The output will tell you where to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the [Cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython) source code which is the “official,” or reference implementation of Python. Some of the standard library modules are implemented in `C`(For the purpose of speed/system calls/library bindings) and `itertools` is one among them. You can find the `itertools.permutations` implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Modules/clinic/itertoolsmodule.c.h#L472).

If you want to understand how the source code is structured you can refer [Your Guide to the CPython Source Code](https://realpython.com/cpython-source-code-guide/#whats-in-the-source-code). To understand `C` extension structure and how to create your own refer [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c)

Comment: does that mean some of the standard modules are already converted into c binary files or  c library, etc?